# Error in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estoy teniendo problemas para lanzar un servicio web en local. Todo el codigo ha sido autogenerado mediante CLI y powershell dotnet asp-codegenerator. Este es el error que lanza el explorador (IE o Chrome, ambos por igual)

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'seguridaddeTelefonia.Models.pruebas_telfContext' while attempting to activate 'seguridaddeTelefonia.Controllers.EstadoLineasController'.

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
Stack 
 Query 
 Cookies 
 Headers 


InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'seguridaddeTelefonia.Models.pruebas_telfContext' while attempting to activate 'seguridaddeTelefonia.Controllers.EstadoLineasController'.

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)


lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)


Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)





Show raw exception details
```

Este es el script que he utilizado para generar los modelos, controladores y vistas:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=$Server;Database=$DB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models

dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name EstadoLineasController -actions -outDir Controllers -m Lineas -dc pruebas_telfContext

dotnet aspnet-codegenerator view EstadoLineas Create -outDir Views -udl -m Lineas -namespace EstadoLineasController
```

Y las dependencias que he instanciado:

```
dotnet add $csproj_name package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language -v 2.2.0
dotnet add $csproj_name package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection -v 2.2.0
dotnet add $csproj_name package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions -v 2.2.0
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -v 2.1.1
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -v 2.1.1"
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -v 2.1.1"
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design -v 2.0.0"
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational -v 2.1.1"
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory -v 2.1.1
```

Se que dotnet lanza un warning si no es una versión menor de 2.2.0, pero de otra forma generaba errores y no creaba los generadores.

El código autogenerado en CS es:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using seguridaddeTelefonia.Models;

namespace seguridaddeTelefonia.Controllers
{
    public class EstadoLineasController : Controller
    {
        private readonly pruebas_telfContext _context;

        public EstadoLineasController(pruebas_telfContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: EstadoLineas
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Lineas.ToListAsync());
    }

    // GET: EstadoLineas/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var lineas = await _context.Lineas
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Numero == id);
        if (lineas == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(lineas);
    }

    // GET: EstadoLineas/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: EstadoLineas/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Numero,Extension,FechaAlta,FechaBaja,Nombre,UneArea,Icc,Sociedades,CentroDeCoste,Tarifa,Puk,Pin,Estado,Operador,Observaciones,Portabilidad,F18,F19")] Lineas lineas)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(lineas);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(lineas);
    }

    // GET: EstadoLineas/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var lineas = await _context.Lineas.FindAsync(id);
        if (lineas == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(lineas);
    }

    // POST: EstadoLineas/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Numero,Extension,FechaAlta,FechaBaja,Nombre,UneArea,Icc,Sociedades,CentroDeCoste,Tarifa,Puk,Pin,Estado,Operador,Observaciones,Portabilidad,F18,F19")] Lineas lineas)
    {
        if (id != lineas.Numero)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(lineas);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!LineasExists(lineas.Numero))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(lineas);
    }

    // GET: EstadoLineas/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var lineas = await _context.Lineas
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Numero == id);
        if (lineas == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(lineas);
    }

    // POST: EstadoLineas/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var lineas = await _context.Lineas.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Lineas.Remove(lineas);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool LineasExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Lineas.Any(e => e.Numero == id);
    }
}
}
```

Fichero startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace seguridaddeTelefonia
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
}
```

Gracias por adelantado!!

P.D: Si creo el proyecto con VS2017 la app funciona sin problema. Pero no si lo hago con la consola. Necesito automatizar la creación de muchos formularios web. De ahí que use powershell y asp-codegenerator.

P.D2: Disculpad por el idioma, no me fijé que es en castellano, tan acostumbrado al ingles... sorry!

Comment: Finalmente he encontrado una solución al problema. Mas tarde la postearé para todos aquellos que pueda seer de ayuda, ahora debo de seguir trabajando. Un saludo!

Comment: Hola diego necesito ayuda,
yo tengo el mismo problema, ¿como lo resolviste?

Comment: Hola Andres, disculpa, acabo de ver el mensaje. Mañana por la mañana te comento si aun necesitas ayuda, tengo el código en el puesto de trabajo. Un saludo!